# How can i include a php file and get the function values in another php file?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So I have 2 files one is mainvariables.php & load_more.php. The load_more.php is a php file on its own since i make an ajax call to it. The mainvariables.php file has 1 function.

It's weird because in my header.php file I include the mainvariables.php and get the returned values but when I try it with the load_more.php file it does not work.

mainvariables.php

```
<?php 
function mainVariables(){
    global $pdo;

    //getting school id for switch statment
    $schoolId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);
    if ($schoolId) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE id = :id';
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':id' => $schoolId));
    }else {
        echo "Not Working";
    }
    //all values of current school
    return  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

?>
```

load_more.php

```
<?php 
// including the config file
require('config.php');
//pdo connct for config.php file
$pdo = connect();
//Include  main variables function 
include('php/mainvariables.php');
//return of main variables function
$specificSchool = mainVariables();

//School Variables
$shcoolOfficialId = $specificSchool[0]["id"];

switch ($shcoolOfficialId) {
    case 1:
         echo "yes";
        break;

    case 2:
        echo "no";
        break;

    default:
        echo "There are no more stories to load.";
        break;
}

?>
```

Just for example my header.php file is like this:

```
<?php
// including the config file
require('config.php');

//pdo connct for config.php file
$pdo = connect();

//Include  main variables function 
include('php/mainvariables.php');
//return of main variables function
$specificSchool = mainvariables();

$shcoolOfficialId = $specificSchool[0]["id"];


?>
```

the header.php does work but the load_more.php does not. I get error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null on line 15 of mainvariables.php. It's the line returning the query. Also it says  Undefined variable: query for the same line as well.

Thank YOU

Comment: So, have you checked that you have `$_GET['id']` variable in your `load_more.php`?

Comment: Also the problem is not with mainvariables.php because it returns what it is supposed to return but instead the load_more.php is causing all this error because load_more.php is a standalone php file so I think that it cannot get $_GET['id'] like header.php which will cause the error in mainvariables.php

Comment: @u_mulder yes actually I need help in what you said. How can i get that say from mainvariables.php. I think I mess it up because both mainvariables.php and load_more.php are in their own file so the reason why it works in header.php is because it is the actual dom and not just a php file.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this statement:

`return  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

If the preceding `if` statement evaluates to false, `$query` will never be defined.  Return a different value if `$schoolId` does not exist, and check the result before using it in the rest of the script.

Comment: I would also move the `return` statement into the `if` block, remove the `else` block, and `return null;` at the end of the function.

Comment: @Sculper Ok so my problem now is since mainvariables.php is in another file but is included into header.php it works because It is able to get $_GET['id'] but if i include it into load_more.php I think it does not grab the $_GET['id'] of the page since load_more.php is its own file not included into the dom. How can I get the $_GET['id']  of the current page but in load_more.php withouth including header.php ?

Comment: Also the problem is not with mainvariables.php because it returns what it is supposed to return but instead the load_more.php is causing all this error because load_more.php is a standalone php file so I think that it cannot get $_GET['id'] like header.php which will cause the error in mainvariables.php

Answer (score 2):

You define `$query` in the scope of the `if statement`, so that variable has not been created outside of the `if statement` so when you run this,

```
return  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It will fail. Why don't you try this,

```
function mainVariables(){
    global $pdo;

    $query = null;

    //getting school id for switch statment
    $schoolId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);
    if ($schoolId) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE id = :id';
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':id' => $schoolId));
    }else {
        echo "Not Working";
    }
                //all values of current school
    return  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

**Edit 1**

I put the fetching of the results in the `if statement`, so only it will only fetch in that part, that way you get the error and you don't need to define the `$query` outside of the `if statement`.

```
function mainVariables(){
    global $pdo;

    //getting school id for switch statment
    $schoolId = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:NULL);
    if ($schoolId) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE id = :id';
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':id' => $schoolId));

        //all values of current school
        return  $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else {
        echo "Not Working";
    }
}
```

Comment: @scipt47 So i tried what you posted and but it still does not solve the overall issues why is it that in load_more.php if I include mainvariables.php it probably cannot get $_GET['id'] since it's not a file included anywhere just a standalone php file that gets called by ajax. How can I match the $_GET['id'] that works in header.php to load_more.php?

Comment: Also the problem is not with mainvariables.php because it returns what it is supposed to return but instead the load_more.php is causing all this error because load_more.php is a standalone php file so I think that it cannot get $_GET['id'] like header.php which will cause the error in mainvariables.php

Comment: @user4589398 you can't access variables in a function like that. You might need to look in to passing variables around.